# php file inclusion and it's manipulation

Tags: php

I am sure that sometimes it happens that you may need main file inclusion and when you write this code :

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../core.php");
```

it will give you such a error :

```
Warning: include(../../../db/mysql.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Softwares\wamp\xampp\htdocs\***\db\db.php on line 38
```

its clear that in core.php  there is another inclusion for db/mysql  and when we include it from sub directories this problem happens

concider you are in a path like this : **/includes/filemanger/**

and you need to connect to your database and core.php needed !

so how to include core.php in **root path** ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. It sounds like you are talking about a relative include that fails when included in a different file. Have you tried using an absolute path?

Answer (score 3):

This is what `set_include_path()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or creating constant

of root path can save you from this type of problems.

```
define('COREPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dir/core.php");

require_once(COREPATH);
```